# creating customized view Mysql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to create a view from three tables. One table is department, second is employee and third one is relationship table work. I need to Create a view ManagerSummary that lists for every department the department name, manager ID and manager name, manager salary and the number of employees in that department. The view will have five columns with headings: DeptName, MgrID, MgrName, MgrSalary and EmpCount.

```
   CREATE VIEW `ManagerSummary` 
    AS SELECT d.dname as DeptName, e.eid as MgrID, e.ename as MgrName, 
     e.salary as MgrSalary,Count(*) as EmpCount
    from emp e, works w,
    inner join dept d 
    on e.deptno=d.deptno
    where e.eid=w.eid AND d.did=w.did
    groupby d.dname
```

This is the query but it is giving me issues in running.

Comment: Be more detailed. What issues is it giving you. Try the query without the view.

Comment: Help us help you - share the table structures

Comment: That `groupby` should be a `group by` at a guess - you don't say what the issue is.